# SVG: Doughnut Hole Inside a Pie Chart

Tags: svg, pie-chart

I'm wanting to cut a doughnut hole inside this SVG pie chart. Can this be done without editing the path dimensions for each slice? Like an overlapping mask perhaps?

```
<svg>
    <path d="M 25 25 L 25 0 A 25 25 0 1 1 0.4428187317827863 29.68453286464311 Z" fill="#45c31b"></path>
    <path d="M 25 25 L 0.4428187317827863 29.68453286464311 A 25 25 0 0 1 24.999999999999996 0 Z" fill="green"></path>
</svg>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjmyrcte/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I entirely understand the effect, but why not just put a circle over it if you don't want to change anything else ?...

```
<circle r="15" cx="25" cy="25" fill="white" />
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjmyrcte/4/)

If you need to let a background through, then you could put it in a group and use a mask (or create the initial paths using some maths so that it already doesn't have a middle section).

```
<svg>
    <defs>
    <mask id="circlemask" >
      <rect fill="white" width="100%" height="100%" />
      <circle r="15" cx="25" cy="25" fill="black"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="blue"/>
    <g mask="url(#circlemask)" >
      <path d="M 25 25 L 25 0 A 25 25 0 1 1 0.4428187317827863 29.68453286464311 Z" fill="#45c31b"></path>
      <path d="M 25 25 L 0.4428187317827863 29.68453286464311 A 25 25 0 0 1 24.999999999999996 0 Z" fill="green"></path>
    </g>  
</svg>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjmyrcte/5/)

I'm not such a fan of a big bask, I would probably prefer just to create the donut section alone, so no clips or masks are needed at all, but if you are working with something already created, this may work.

Comment: It's not ideal, as the fill would need to be transparent.